# mount.nfs: /sysroot is busy or already mounted (CentOS 7 PXE)

Tags: linux, dhcp, nfs, pxe, tftp

Настроил DHCP, TFTP и NFS сервер (все на одной системе), пытаюсь загрузиться с другого компьютера по локальной сети. До определенного момента все нормально, а потом "mount.nfs: /sysroot is busy or already mounted" и через некоторое время приглашение для ввода "dracut:#".
В чем может быть проблема или хотя бы где ее искать?

Comment: На другом компьютере с другим дистрибутивом "random: crng init done", затем dracut-initqueue timeout и опять приглашение к вводу "dracut:/#"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла замена NFS сервера на HTTP